# Script de función que se vaya ejecutando cada cierto tiempo

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si se podría hacer una función que se vaya ejecutando cada cierto tiempo en Java, por ejemplo, cada 60 segundos, pero en un script.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hola");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usarías el método "sleep" te la clase "Thread", simplemente pesándole un número de microsegundos.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    //Imprime "hola" cada 5 segundos
    hola( 5 );
}

public static void hola( int seconds ) {

    System.out.println( "Hola" );
    Thread.sleep ( seconds * 1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando Java SE, puedes intentar con [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Aquí un ejemplo de una tarea que se ejecuta cada 5 segundos por un minuto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        () -> System.out.println("hola"),
        0,
        5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(
        () -> {
            future.cancel(true);
            //permite que la aplicación general termine
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

La ventaja de este método es que la tarea se ejecuta en un hilo paralelo al de la aplicación principal. Cuando usas `Thread.sleep` se paraliza el hilo en el cual se ejecuta la tarea, y si es el hilo principal (main), entonces se paraliza toda la aplicación.